# Conditional Probability Mass function

Tags: probability

How do I prove this probability equation:

Suppose we have $N$ is Poisson($\lambda$), and if we have that $X$ is a binomial random variable Bin($N,p$). If we know what $N$ is we get:

$$P(X=k| N)={N\choose k}p^k(1-p)^{N-k}$$

What is the probability mass function of $X$?

I know that the result follows a Poisson random variable, but I don't know how to algebraically show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim $X$ ~ Pois($\lambda p$)

$$P(X=k)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty P(X=k+r|N=k+r) = \sum P(X=k|N=k+r)P(X=k+r) = \sum {k+r \choose k}p^k(1-p)^re^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda p)^{k+r}}{(k+r)!}$$

$$= \frac{e^{-\lambda p^k}}{k!}e^{\lambda(1-p)}= e^{-\lambda p}\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}$$ Therefore we are done!

Comment: how did u get the second equality? Can u please elaborate on that step?

Comment: There was a typo!